# Filter foreign key objects in django template

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have the following model which is used to "archive" a post (i.e if it is created for a post by a user, that post is now hidden from that user)

models.py

```
class ArchivedFlag(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='archived_commits')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Commit,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='archived_flag')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='archives')
```

In a particular template, I want logic based on whether an ArchivedFlag exists for both the current user's group and the current post being examined.

template.html

```
{% for p in posts %}

<form action="{% url 'archive_posts' p.oid %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}">

    {% if <...an archived flag exists with post==post and group==user.group...> %}
        <...Do stuff for archived post...>
        <button type="submit", name="p_oid", value="{{ p.oid }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Restore</button>
    {% else %}
        <...do stuff for unarchived post...>
        <button type="submit", name="p_oid", value="{{ p.oid }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Archive</button>
    {% endif %}

</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to do this in a django template? I can't find any information on filtering in a template so perhaps this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter/query in a Django template.

But, if you give your Commit model a property model method like is_archived, you could use that in a conditional.

The docs for model methods are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

So your Commit model could have a property that returns a boolean, looking like this:

```
@property
def is_archived(self):
    return <however you know it's archived>
```

Then you can use the pattern you have in your question like this:

```
{%for post in posts %}
  {% if post.is_archived %}
    do a thing
  {% else %}
    do a different thing
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```